# Duvida sobre mapa da google

Tags: css, google-maps

Olá,
Eu tenho uma duvida sobre o mapa da google e não consigo encontrar uma resposta na internet, basicamente eu queria usar um mapa com cores pretas interactivo como o mapa da google e eu já tive a fazer varias pesquisas para saber se dava para personalizar as cores do mapa e não encontrei nada, a unica coisa que encontrei era este estilo de mapa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas as cores não ficam bem no meu site e não se percebe a fronteira entre portugal e Espanha. 

O que eu quero saber é se existe alguma forma e mudar as cores e melhorar o mapa com algum código no css ou algo do genero.

o mapa não pode perder a interactividade com o utilizador, para a pessoa poder dar zoom e mover o mapa como preferir.

Comment: Cara, na boa, eu não demorei 2 minutos para achar isso no Google. https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ e a Doc oficial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: @Geremias Tive mais ou menos 4 horas a pesquisar mapas da google pretos e definições do mapa e não encontrei nada parecido! obrigado!